# Howto: Pause and Play flexslider based on click event (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flexslider

1. I am trying to bind the `slider.pause()` and `slider.play()` events to my buttons (see code below).
2. It works **unless I click the play button twice** or I click the play button **while the slider is running**.
3. Then it seems to run ***another*** instance (or something) as it runs at twice the speed and the pause button no longer stops slider

Question: Is there a way to test whether the slider is running before calling `slider.play()` or are the pause() and/or play() calls in the wrong place?

Please advise.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        slideshowSpeed: 2000,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        touch: true,
        controlsContainer: ".fs-container",
        controlNav: true,
        manualControls: ".flex-control-nav li",
        start: function(slider) {
            $('.icon-pause').click(function(){
                slider.pause();
            });

            $('.icon-play').click(function(){
                slider.play();                      
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

7 months old question, but yea the `start` property on flexslider fires every time an animation starts.

So the code you have above is binding rebinding the click event.

Instead you want something like:

```
        $('.icon-pause').click(function(){
            $('#your_slider_id').pause();
        });
```

And you'd put this in your page init functions -- or anywhere, just not inside the flexslider initialization.

(Of course `.play()` is also a method.)

Comment: The other answer is working. See the basic API: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/video.html

Comment: @marwils, nice. This answer was written before priyaqb posted. I can't even remember it anymore. Anyone still looking, see priyaqb's answer.

Answer (score 23):

Try:

`$('.flex-slider').flexslider('pause');` and `$('.flex-slider').flexslider('play');`.